# PHP - extracting words from a list in a text

Tags: php

I have a list of whitelisted words: `kitchen chair table`;

Given a text, I would like to know which of those white-listed words are in it.

What would be a *good* way to achieve this? I mean, easy to understand, with good performances?

Comment: are you looking for specific words or just words?

Comment: `array_unique(explode(" ", $words))` will give you an array with all the different words

Comment: @Mr D: specific words - I have a whitelist already compiled

Comment: @Truth: sorry, I don't understand you comment.

Comment: @dan: It appears that at least 7 people understand my comment, and agree with it. "I want to know which of **those** words are in it, with PHP" What are **those** words? What do you want to do with them? What are you trying to achieve? And what have you tried??

Comment: @Truth: I'll try to make it clearer - thanks for pointing it out. Probably you should have made your first comment clearer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you should use a regex with word boundaries. If you don't and just rely on string positions, words like "heat" will be matched inside words like "cheat"

```
$word_list = "kitchen chair table tables";
$words = explode( ' ', $word_list);

$text = 'There is a table in the kitchen';

foreach( $words as $word) {
    if( preg_match( '/\b' . $word . '\b/', $text)) {
        echo "$word is in the text\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
kitchen is in the text 
table is in the text
```

Note that this will not match `table` if the `$text` only had `tables` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very clear question but something like this may work for you:

```
$str = "kitchen chair table";
$search = "kitchen bathroom chair";
$arr1 = explode(' ', $str);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $search);
print_r(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => kitchen
    [1] => chair
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//list of words
$myArray = array('kitchen', 'chair', 'table');

foreach($myArray as $word){
    if(stristr($textBody, $word) !== false){
    // word's in there
    }
}
```

Comment: $textBody would be the "any text" part

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the wordlist with space using php [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Then it'll return you an array. Same thing will be done with input text. In this way, you will have two Array.

After that you can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function, that will return the common words in both Array.

```
$array = explode(' ',$wordlist);
$result = array_intersect($array, $inputarray);
```

$result will contain all common words.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know how often those words are in the string or their exact position?
If not, I suggest you convert your list to an array with "explode(' ', $list)".
Then you iterate through that array and search with strpos.

I can provide example code if you want :)

If you need the positions and all occurrences you will have to use a regex.